# Composition with exponent Sobolev Space

Tags: sobolev-spaces, function-and-relation-composition

I have a problem with following statement:
We have $f \in W^{1,1}(B) (B-ball\ in\ \mathbb{R^n}), \ \nabla f \ e^{f} - $ integrable $\Rightarrow \ e^f \in W^{1,1}$

I've started with a sequence of functions $f_n \in C^1(B) \bigcap W^{1,1}(B)$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $W^{1,1}(B)$.
Next by Fatou's lemma we have
$$\int\limits_B e^f dx \le \lim\inf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_{B} e^{f_n} dx$$
But why right side of inequality have a limit?

Comment: To use Fatou's Lemma, you have first to verify that $\sup \int e^{f_n}$ is finite. How have you proved it?

Comment: In Fatou's Lemma we need only that $f_n \ge 0, \ f_n - measurable$

Answer (score 0):

I think that I should use $f_n$ such that
$$f_n (x)= \left\{\begin{array}\ 
n, \ f(x)>n \\
f, \ |f(x)|\le n \\
-n, \ f(x)<-n
\end{array}\right.$$
So we have that 
\begin{equation}
\nabla f_n (x)= \left\{\begin{array}\ 
0, \ f(x)>n \\
\nabla f, \ |f(x)|\le n \\
0, \ f(x)<-n
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
And $f_n\in W^{1,1}(B), \ f_n \rightarrow f \ \in W^{1,1}(B)$

I have to prove that $e^{f_n} \in W^{1,1}(B)$. But this follows from  $e^{f_n}\le e^n$ and $|\nabla f_n| e^{f_n}\le |\nabla f|e^f$
.

Then I should use Poincare inequality for proving that $\lim\int\limits_{B}e^{f_n}dx<+\infty$

Am I right?